# Does this subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ have a a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

The set of matrices $g$ characterized by

$g=\begin{pmatrix}a&ib\\ ic&d\end{pmatrix}$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ad+bc=1$,

can be easily shown to be a subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

They satisfy the following equation:

$g^{-1}= -\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}g^\dagger\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$

What is the name of this subgroup?

Comment: It's the conjugate of $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$ by the diagonal matrix $diag(i,1)$; it's unclear whether it deserves a name.